# Orientation Problem

Tags: android, android-activity

When i changed screen from portrait mode to land scape mode then the dialog box which appeared in portrait mode is automatically wear off in land scape mode.
can any one tell me the solution for this..

Comment: **automatically wear off in land scape mode** means what ?

Comment: means no dialog box appear in land scape mode when i change screen from portrait mode to land scape mode.

Comment: what code are you using to create the dialog box?

Comment: public void showDialog(String message)
 {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setMessage(message);
  builder.setCancelable(false);
  builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
   {
    dialog.dismiss();
   }
  });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you change the orientation activity is re-create so what ever ur GUI is also re-create.

https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidProgressDialogSample
 link has project that might be useful for u